# Add field to JSON api to retrieve date of build job

Tags: jenkins

At the moment, in Jenkins 2.204.1, using JSON API it is not possible to retrieve date of build job. How can I add that field to build info?

Answer (score 0):

On the bottom right of the build page there is an API link. There I found this URL for querying the build timestamp:

- https://**JENKINSROOT**/job/**JOBNAME**/**BUILDNUM**/buildTimestamp

Example output: `2/28/20 10:23 PM`

This could be local-dependent.

---

You can also specify a date format:

- https://**JENKINSROOT**/job/**JOBNAME**/**BUILDNUM**/buildTimestamp?format=yyyy/MM/dd+HH:mm

Example output: `2020/02/28 22:23`

---

To get latest build you can use literal "lastBuild" in place of BUILDNUM, e. g.:

- https://**JENKINSROOT**/job/**JOBNAME**/lastBuild/buildTimestamp